# Unique record but only for a given parent in Laravel 5.5

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have 2 database models, both with a field for URL so you can access them. In the frontend I'd do something like this to access it:

```
/{{ $parent->url }}/{{ $child->url }}
```

Validating that the parent URL is easy, I just ensure it's required and unique for that table. But the child one is a bit tricker. I need the URL to be unique but only if the records share the same parent. Currently my validation rule for creating a new record is:

```
'url' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:child_table,url',
```

and updated with:

```
'url' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:child_table,url,' . $id,
```

But that means **EVERY** URL must be unique and I'd rather not enforce that rule. I know the parent record ID so is there a way to say URL must be unique but only for records with this parent ID?

To be absolutely clear, this isn't allowed:

```
/parent1/child1
/parent1/child1
```

But this is:

```
/parent1/child1
/parent2/child1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this can help you achieve that:

```
Rule::unique('child_table', 'url')->where(function ($query) use ($parentId) {
    return $query->where('parrent_id', $parentId);
})
```

Comment: The same rule doesn't work when updating a record. Basically when you edit a record and without making any change click on save. It still fires up the validation instead it should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up ever so slightly more complicated if anyone ever needs this:

```
'url' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', Rule::unique('child_table', 'url')->where(function($query) use ($parentId) {
    return $query->where('parentId', '=', $parentId);
})],
```

Comment: You can remove `'='`, where uses that operator by default, so you can only have `'parent_id', $parentId`